# WASM Blazor is reporting an inner object as null when used as a parameter to a nested component (VS2022/.Net core 6)

Tags: c#, components, webassembly, blazor-webassembly, asp.net-core-6.0

I have built a really simple example:

**tester.razor**:

```
@page "/test"
@using VetJobSearch.UI.ViewModels
<EditForm Model=@outerClass>    
    <OuterComponent OuterClass="@outerClass"/>
</EditForm>
```

**OuterComponent.razor**:

```
@using ViewModels
<InnerComponent InnerClass=OuterClass.InnerClass/>
@code {
    [Parameter] public OuterClass OuterClass { get; set; } = new OuterClass() 
    { InnerClass = new InnerClass() };
}
```

**InnerComponent.razor**:

```
@using ViewModels
<div>Inner Component</div>      
<InputText @bind-Value=InnerClass.InnerText />
@code {
   [Parameter] public InnerClass InnerClass { get; set; } = new InnerClass();
}
```

And here are the classes themselves:

```
public class OuterClass
{
    public string? OuterText {  get; set; }
    public InnerClass? InnerClass { get; set; }
}

public class InnerClass
{ 
    public string? InnerText{  get; set; }
}
```

I must be missing something because every time i run it, I get:

> Unhandled exception rendering component: Object reference not set to
> an instance of an object.
>
> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Kindly show your `outerClass` object. Did you just intanciate it using `new OuterClass()`?

Comment: Its actually instantiated in the top "file": OuterComponent.razor:

Comment: It will be the default value if you did not assign a value for OuterClass parameter. What I am looking for is what did you assign to your model `outerClass`? It is probably just `new OuterClass()` with a `null` value for property `InnerClass`

Comment: oh! i forgot my code for that one (i had it in a codebehind file).  I'll add it

Comment: Actually that was it...i was confusing the parameter variable.  Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out i missed the outermost declaration.  Thank you iamrafelperez!